# Stargate API Rate Limiter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

Planning a migration from DataStax Enterprise to Astra DB, and I'm curious on some points:

1. If we impose rate limiting on API endpoints exposed by Stargate?
2. If answer is yes, what kind of rate limiting algorithm do we impose?
3. What are the expected errors if the rate limiting threshold is exceeded?

Comment: In the future, please ask only one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Astra DB instances on the free tier are [limited to 4K operations per second](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/plan/planning.html#_workloads). Paying customers can have the rate limits raised for their databases.

To respond to your questions directly:

1. Limits are not imposed on Stargate API endpoints directly -- the limits are on the database itself.
2. We can't share that information publicly here but if get in contact with us directly, we would be happy to discuss.
3. The clients will get generic timeout and/or authentication errors.